# Angular JS - to tag single class for multiple expressions in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am  trying to find the syntax to tag single class for multiple expressions in ng-class:

```
<li class="data-ng-class: {'left': $even, 'first-left': (year==recentActiveYear && $index == 1) 'right': $odd, 'first-right': $index == 1, 'first-recentYear': year==recentActiveYear}" >
```

When I use the above one, the first-left class is not getting applied.
Please, can anyone help with correct syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying this:

```
<li data-ng-class="{ 'left': $even, 'first-left': (year==recentActiveYear && $index == 1), 'right': $odd, 'first-right': $index == 1, 'first-recentYear': year==recentActiveYear }">
```

One problem with your code is that `ng-class` is it's own attribute and shouldn't be place inside of a class attribute.

The last thing I saw was that you had a syntax error between `'first-left'` and `'right'`.  You were missing a `,` between the two.